# Swift - How to sort an array of custom class?

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, sorting

This is my code.  As you see, I am using a custom class. I create an array of students, and I want to sort it.  I know I have to use the `sort` function, but I don't know how to use it.  I understood that I need to create a function that takes two students and returns a boolean.

**Even though I know that the code is not 100% correct, I know I want to focus on calling the sort function.**

```
class Subject{

    var id:Int

    var name: String

    init(id:Int, name:String){

        self.id = id

        self.name = name

    }

}



class Helper{

    static func isFirstStudentBetterThanTheSecondStudent(student1: Student, student2: Student) -> Bool{

        if student1.subjects == nil{

            return false

        }

        var student1Marks: Double = 0

        for index in student1.marks!{

            student1Marks += index

        }



        var student2Marks :Double = 0

        for index in student2.marks!{

            student2Marks += index

        }



        return student1Marks > student2Marks

    }

}



let subject1 = Subject(id: 1, name: "subject 1")

let subject2 = Subject(id: 2, name: "subject 2")

let subject3 = Subject(id: 3, name: "subject 3")



let student1 = Student(number: 1, fullName: "student 1")

student1.addSubject(subject1, result: 10)

student1.addSubject(subject2, result: 20)

student1.addSubject(subject3, result: 30)



let student2 = Student(number: 2, fullName: "student 2")

student2.addSubject(subject1, result: 100)

student2.addSubject(subject2, result: 200)

student2.addSubject(subject3, result: 300)



let students = [student1, student2]
```

I need to sort the students array according to my helper static function.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` function takes a closure as it is parameter

```
let sortedStudent = students.sort({ Helper.isFirstStudentBetterThanTheSecondStudent ($0, student2: $1 ) } )
```

and the same result with full syntax:

```
let sortedSudents2 = students.sort({(s1: Student, s2:Student) -> Bool in return Helper.isFirstStudentBetterThanTheSecondStudent(student1, student2: student2)})
```

[More details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)